# How to fasten the avatar's foots on the ground

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, xna-4.0, kinect-sdk

I'm developing a Kinect Project using C# and XNA 4.0.Now facing a problem that I couldn't solve.When the player bend to near side , the avatar's foots are leaving the ground and it is moving like holding its hips center.Any way fasten the avatar on the ground? Here is my codes firstly the uptade method :

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    animationPlayer.Update(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime, true, Matrix.Identity);
    // Update saved state.
    this.previousKeyboard = this.currentKeyboard;

    // If the sensor is not found, not running, or not connected, stop now
    if (null == this.chooser || null == this.Chooser.Sensor || false == this.Chooser.Sensor.IsRunning || this.Chooser.Sensor.Status != KinectStatus.Connected)
    {
        return;
    }

    bool newFrame = false;



    using (var skeletonFrame = this.Chooser.Sensor.SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame(0))
    {
        // Sometimes we get a null frame back if no data is ready
        if (null != skeletonFrame)
        {
            newFrame = true;

            // Reallocate if necessary
            if (null == SkeletonData || SkeletonData.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
            {
                SkeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            }

            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(SkeletonData);

            // Select the first tracked skeleton we see to avateer
            Skeleton rawSkeleton =
                (from s in SkeletonData
                 where s != null && s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                 select s).FirstOrDefault();

            if (null != this.animator)
            {
                if (null != rawSkeleton)
                {
                    this.animator.CopySkeleton(rawSkeleton);
                    this.animator.FloorClipPlane = skeletonFrame.FloorClipPlane;

                    // Reset the filters if the skeleton was not seen before now
                    if (this.skeletonDetected == false)
                    {
                        this.animator.Reset();
                    }

                    this.skeletonDetected = true;
                    this.animator.SkeletonVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.skeletonDetected = false;
                    this.animator.SkeletonVisible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (newFrame)
    {
        // Call the stream update manually as they are not a game component
        if (null != this.depthStream && null != this.skeletonStream)
        {
            this.depthStream.Update(gameTime);
            this.skeletonStream.Update(gameTime, SkeletonData);

        }

        // Update the avatar renderer
        if (null != this.animator)
        {
            this.animator.SkeletonDrawn = false;
        }
    }

    this.HandleInput();
    this.UpdateCamera(gameTime);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

And the bones transforms :

```
 private void SetJointTransformation(BoneOrientation bone, Skeleton skeleton, Matrix bindRoot, ref Matrix[] boneTransforms)
{
    // Always look at the skeleton root
    if (bone.StartJoint == JointType.HipCenter && bone.EndJoint == JointType.HipCenter)
    {
        // Unless in seated mode, the hip center is special - it is the root of the NuiSkeleton and describes the skeleton orientation in the world
        // (camera) coordinate system. All other bones/joint orientations in the hierarchy have hip center as one of their parents.
        // However, if in seated mode, the shoulder center then holds the skeleton orientation in the world (camera) coordinate system.
        bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
        Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

        //Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Here we create a rotation matrix for the hips from the inverse of the bind pose
        // for the pelvis rotation and the inverse of the bind pose for the root node (0) in the Dude model.
        // This multiplication effectively removes the initial 90 degree rotations set in the first two model nodes.
        Matrix pelvis = boneTransforms[1];
        pelvis.Translation = Vector3.Zero; // Ensure pure rotation as we explicitly set world translation from the Kinect camera below.
        Matrix invPelvis = Matrix.Invert(pelvis);

        //Matrix combined = (invBindRoot * hipOrientation) * invPelvis;
        Matrix combined = invBindRoot * invPelvis;
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(180));
        combined *= adjustment;
        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ShoulderCenter)
    {
        // This contains an absolute rotation if we are in seated mode, or the hip center is not tracked, as the HipCenter will be identity
        if (this.chooser.SeatedMode || (this.Chooser.SeatedMode == false && skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipCenter].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked))
        {
            bindRoot.Translation = Vector3.Zero;
            Matrix invBindRoot = Matrix.Invert(bindRoot);

            Matrix hipOrientation = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

            // We can use the same method as in HipCenter above to invert the root and pelvis bind pose,
            // however, alternately we can also explicitly swap axes and adjust the rotations to get from
            // the Kinect rotation to the model hip orientation, similar to what we do for the following joints/bones.

            // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
            // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
            Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(hipOrientation);    // XYZ
            Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
            Matrix combined = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

            // Add a small adjustment rotation to manually correct for the rotation in the parent bind
            // pose node in the model mesh - this can be found by looking in the FBX or in 3DSMax/Maya.
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));
            combined *= adjustment;
            Matrix adjustment2 = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));
            combined *= adjustment2;

            // Although not strictly correct, we apply this to the hip center, as all other bones are children of this joint.
            // Application at the spine or shoulder center instead would require manually updating of the bone orientations below for the whole body to move when the shoulders twist or tilt.
            this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(JointType.HipCenter, combined, true, ref boneTransforms);
        }
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.Spine)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // The Dude appears to lean back too far compared to a real person, so here we adjust this lean.
        this.CorrectBackwardsLean(skeleton, ref tempMat);

        // Also add a small constant adjustment rotation to correct for the hip center to spine bone being at a rear-tilted angle in the Kinect skeleton.
        // The dude should now look more straight ahead when avateering
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(20));  // 20 degree rotation around the local Kinect x axis for the spine bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        // Set the corresponding matrix in the avatar using the translation table we specified.
        // Note for the spine and shoulder center rotations, we could also try to spread the angle
        // over all the Avatar skeleton spine joints, causing a more curved back, rather than apply
        // it all to one joint, as we do here.
        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.Head)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton head bones being defined pointing looking slightly down, not vertical.
        // The dude should now look more straight ahead when avateering
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-30));  // -30 degree rotation around the local Kinect x axis for the head bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +X left, +Y up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +Z left, +X up, +Y forward
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, kinectRotation.Z, kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        // Set the corresponding matrix in the avatar using the translation table we specified
        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.WristLeft)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowLeft)
        {

            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton shoulder/upper arm bones.
            // The dude should now be able to have arms correctly down at his sides when avateering
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(-15));  // -15 degree rotation around the local Kinect z axis for the upper arm bone.
            tempMat *= adjustment;
        }

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X down, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z backwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.Z, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.HandLeft)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton wist/hand bone.
        // The dude should now have the palm of his hands toward his body when arms are straight down
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));  // -90 degree rotation around the local Kinect y axis for the wrist-hand bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X down, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z backwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, kinectRotation.X, -kinectRotation.Z, kinectRotation.W);
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowRight || bone.EndJoint == JointType.WristRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.ElbowRight)
        {
            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton shoulder/upper arm bones.
            // The dude should now be able to have arms correctly down at his sides when avateering
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(15));  // 15 degree rotation around the local Kinect  z axis for the upper arm bone.
            tempMat *= adjustment;
        }

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y back, +Z down
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.Z, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.HandRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

        // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton wist/hand bone.
        // The dude should now have the palm of his hands toward his body when arms are straight down
        Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(90));  // -90 degree rotation around the local Kinect y axis for the wrist-hand bone.
        tempMat *= adjustment;

        // Kinect = +Y along arm, +X up, +Z forward in body coordinate system
        // Avatar = +X along arm, +Y down, +Z forwards
        Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat);    // XYZ
        Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(kinectRotation.Y, -kinectRotation.X, kinectRotation.Z, kinectRotation.W); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
        tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

        this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.KneeLeft)
    {
        // Combine the two joint rotations from the hip and knee
        Matrix hipLeft = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(skeleton.BoneOrientations[JointType.HipLeft].HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix kneeLeft = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix combined = kneeLeft * hipLeft;

        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, combined, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.AnkleLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.AnkleRight)
    {
        Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.KneeRight)
    {
        // Combine the two joint rotations from the hip and knee
        Matrix hipRight = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(skeleton.BoneOrientations[JointType.HipRight].HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix kneeRight = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);
        Matrix combined = kneeRight * hipRight;

        this.SetLegMatrix(bone.EndJoint, combined, ref boneTransforms);
    }
    else if (bone.EndJoint == JointType.FootLeft || bone.EndJoint == JointType.FootRight)
    {
        // Only set this if we actually have a good track on this and the parent
        if (skeleton.Joints[bone.EndJoint].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && skeleton.Joints[skeleton.BoneOrientations[bone.EndJoint].StartJoint].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
        {
            Matrix tempMat = KinectHelper.Matrix4ToXNAMatrix(bone.HierarchicalRotation.Matrix);

            // Add a small adjustment rotation to correct for the avatar skeleton foot bones being defined pointing down at 45 degrees, not horizontal
            Matrix adjustment = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(-45));
            tempMat *= adjustment;

            // Kinect = +Y along foot (fwd), +Z up, +X right in body coordinate system
            // Avatar = +X along foot (fwd), +Y up, +Z right
            Quaternion kinectRotation = KinectHelper.DecomposeMatRot(tempMat); // XYZ
            Quaternion avatarRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // transform from Kinect to avatar coordinate system
            tempMat = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(avatarRotation);

            this.ReplaceBoneMatrix(bone.EndJoint, tempMat, false, ref boneTransforms);
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: I haven't used the kinect api before, but I have had to debug animation problems. Have you tried narrowing the bug down to one of the if blocks by commenting them out one at a time?

Comment: I have get it what do you mean.Yes I have tried to comment out some blocks but it doesn't work with this way.